# Error on extending String library in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I wanted to parse JSON strings and convert them into hash.

I created a method called `to_h` and put it in the `String` class, and it worked. This is how I intended to use it `Net::HTTP.get_response(uri).body.to_h`
Here's the method:

```
class String
   def to_h
     JSON.parse(self)
   end
end
```

But when I change it's name to `to_hash`, I get the following error on the same string `Net::HTTP.get_response(uri).body`.

```
A JSON text must at least contain two octets! (JSON::ParserError)
```

I don't understand why it's doing this. Can anyone help me with this.
Thanks :)

Comment: `JSON.parse('') #=> JSON::ParserError: A JSON text must at least contain two octets!` I don't think this string extensions makes any sense, a string is fundamentally different from a dictionary. Just because string encoded JSON happens to parse to a hash does not mean you should add a method like this. The semantics of `String#to_h` are not obvious at all, so as a reader of your code I'd much rather see an explicit call to `JSON.parse`.

Comment: I appreciate your opinion. What do you suggest?

Comment: What's wrong with `JSON.parse`?

Comment: I don't like doing `JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get_response(uri).body)` every time I have to type this. Something like `Net::HTTP.get_response(uri).body.from_json` makes it easier to write for me.

Comment: JSON.parse need a json content and not an ordinary string. It atleast need a key and its value.

Comment: I understand @kvivek. The string is valid. The problem is that the error occurs only if the name is `to_hash`.

Comment: @kvivek _"JSON.parse [..] at least need a key and its value"_ – no, it doesn't. `JSON.parse('"foo"')`, `JSON.parse('123')`, `JSON.parse('true')` are all valid.

Comment: @dhaliman how do you call your `to_h` / `to_hash` method? Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

you call your method with Net::HTTP.get_response(uri).to_h

I suspect that the object that is returned by get_response() is not a String, but an object that already has a to_hash method.
Your version of to_hash is probably not used because you called it on a non String object.

Comment: I've made an edit. I was calling it like this `Net::HTTP.get_response(uri).body.to_h`

Comment: I get the same error when I call JSON.parse with an empty string as argument. I think your response body is empty.